# *"Человек выходит в свет только когда обретает самостоятельность".*

Tags: пунктуация

**Человек выходит в свет только когда обретает самостоятельность.**

Полагаю, запятой в предложении не требуется, так как перед союзом стоит ограничительная частица "только". А при каких еще случаях запятая перед подчинительным союзом не ставится?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы не совсем правы. Запятая в приведенном примере ставится, но не перед подчинительным союзом, а перед усилительной частицей. *Человек выходит в свет, только когда обретает самостоятельность.* Или *Человек выходит в свет только тогда, когда обретает самостоятельность.*

По общему правилу главная часть от придаточной отделяется запятой. Но если придаточная часть представляет собой несколько однородных придаточных предложений, то запятая ставится по правилу постановки знаков при однородных членах. Т.е., если однородные придаточные соединены повторяющимся или двойным союзом, или между ними противительные отношения, то запятая будет ставиться между однородными придаточными.

См. также у Розенталя [здесь](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Запятая между главной частью и придаточной, присоединяемой простым союзом или союзным словом, не ставится:
а) если перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом стоит сочинительный союз и (или частица): Не вернул он мне книгу и когда прочитал ее; Скоро станет известно и кто приедет на праздник;
б) если перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом есть частица не: Готовиться к экзаменам надо не когда начнется сессия, а задолго до этого (не… а);
в) если придаточная часть усечена до одного союзного слова (одиночно употребленное союзное слово теряет функцию придаточного предложения): Учащимся назначили экзамен, но не уточнили когда; Со стороны проспекта кто-то шел — издали было неясно кто (Пелев.);
г) если придаточная часть, благодаря союзам и, или, включается в ряд однородных членов: Во время работы и когда вышел фильм, я не очень-то разобрался в нем (газ.); И вспомнил незабвенный «Фрегат „Палладу“» и как Григорович вкатился в Париж лет восемьдесят назад! (Булг.); Ему вдруг захотелось тепла и чтоб зима тоже была теплая (Ард.); Приезжай через неделю или когда тебе захочется.

Comment: Примечание 3. Если перед подчинительным союзом стоят слова особенно, в частности, а именно, то есть, а также и т.п. с присоединительным значением, то запятая после этих слов не ставится, например: Партизаны проявляли огромную находчивость и исключительное хладнокровие, особенно когда попадали в окружение; Экспедицию придется закончить досрочно при неблагоприятных условиях, а именно если начнется сезон дождей; Автор имеет право на получение 60% гонорара в соответствии с условиями договора, то есть когда рукопись будет одобрена издательством.